# Piping data into jobs in Hadoop MR/Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie, cascading

I have three different type of jobs running on the data in HDFS.
These three jobs have to be run separately in the current scenario.
Now, `we want to run the three jobs together by piping the OUTPUT data of one job to the other job without writing the data in HDFS to improve the architecture and overall performance.`

Any suggestions are welcome for this scenario.

PS : Oozie is not fitting for the workflow.Cascading framework is also ruled out because of Scalability issues.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop inherently writes to storage (e.g. HDFS) after M/R steps.  If you want something in memory, maybe you need to look into something like [Spark.](https://spark.apache.org/)

Comment: Thanks Marc. We are looking into that option also.

Answer (score 0):

Oozie helps to chain multiple hadoop jobs(mapreduce, pig, hive, java etc.) together to form a data pipeline application. The built-in support of **scheduling** and **hadoop-related functions** makes dev's life much easier to manage complex hadoop related jobs.

However Oozie doesn't necessarily eliminate data storage in HDFS or other forms such as local file system or database, etc. To do that you would need to introduce some in-memory data store, message-queue systems or other system which works for the scale of data you have.

Comment: I am working on the Oozie workflow process, lets c if something useful comes out of it. Is cascading a good approach for my situation?

Comment: Cascading may help in your scenario. It's similar to Pig or Hive in the sense that they convert data transformation presented in domain specific languages (pig latin, hive or java) to map/reduce jobs underneath. It helps performance assuming that a well maintained compiler can do a better job than individual developer. :)

Comment: thanks Paul .. as of now Cascading is not in picture because of scalability issues.We are looking forward to making PIG scripts for out MR jobs and one other possible solution is Crunch.

Answer (score -1):

you may try using HUE.
 Refer:  http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/10/new-in-cdh-5-2-new-security-app-and-more-in-hue/

CDH 5.2 includes important new usability functionality via Hue, the open source GUI that makes Apache Hadoop easy to use. In addition to shipping a brand-new app for managing security permissions, this release is particularly feature-packed, and is becoming a great complement to BI tools from Cloudera partners like Tableau, MicroStrategy, and Zoomdata because a more usable Hadoop translates into better BI overall across your organization!